# How to connect AngularJS with MySQL to save, read and access levels make easy?

Tags: mysql, angularjs, firebase-realtime-database, strapi, directus

I used Firebase before. It was super simple, but It works only with non-relational database. I want to find something similar for MySQL but open source.

I found this two:

- https://directus.io/
- https://strapi.io/

I can't connect both to my old database or it seems complicated. I also can't find AngularJS integration. I found JavaScript integration for Strapi, but is unmaintained (https://github.com/strapi/strapi-sdk-javascript). If you recommend Strapi or Directus, is there any easy way to connect it to old database and JavaScript sdk?

Comment: So you want to connect a mysql-database directly to your AngularJs Frontend?
There is an official MySQL-node.js package that you could use, but obviously it's a most questionable idea to connect the database to the frontend directly...

Comment: I want to make save, read and permissions simple. So I think I need some lightweight bare bones CMS.

Answer (score 1):

If you install Directus clean, you can then just import your existing SQL tables/content and it will let you manage it. Should be very quick and easy to setup! There's a whole community on Slack that can help you out on that too:

https://directus.chat

Comment: I couldn't find how to import existing SQL tables/content. I will be grateful if you could share instruction.

Comment: Excellent! If this resolved your issue you can upvote and mark as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

By using Strapi you will not be able to import a database structure and generate automatically the API from it.

After that, in few clicks you will be able to map your Strapi content types (models) on your database table structure.

Let me know if you have any questions.